# Make complierOptions generate warnings instead of errors in tsconfig

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

Is there a way to indicate in the tsconfig.json file the options noUnusedLocals and noUnusedParameters as warnings instead of errors that block the compilation?

Currently I use them in the tsconfig.json file like this :

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true
  },
```

I tried the option :

"no-unused-variable": true,

in the tslint.json file but it doesn't detect errors like the tsc, and in visual studio code I can't see them underlined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you may have seen, Visual Studio Code has a hack to display noUnusedLocals and noUnusedParameters problems as warnings during live editing (the `typescript.reportStyleChecksAsWarnings` setting, which defaults to true).  The tslint extension does not display these problems at all because they require type information, which [the tslint extension does not support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint#user-content-the-tslint-%60no-unused-variable%60-rule-doesn't-report-warnings-any-more%3F).

If the issue is that you are using something like `tsc --noEmitOnError` and you don't want noUnusedLocals/noUnusedParameters errors to block the emit, then you could have Visual Studio Code use one `tsconfig.json` that has noUnusedLocals/noUnusedParameters enabled and have your command line builds use `tsc` with a separate `tsconfig.json` that has the options disabled, plus `tslint` with no-unused-variable.

Comment: in a team where multiple people touch the tsconfig file, this becomes very easily error-prone. Is it still the recommended solution?

Comment: Yes this is a dilemma. The linter and vs code plugin should support it as warning. Or tsconfig (for specific rules). The best solution could be to switch to [eslint](https://eslint.org/) if possible. Since [tslint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) is (officially) deprecated in favor of eslint. Typescript is supported by [plugin](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint).